# Creating a software to post and manage topics in a lot of forums

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, forum

I have had an idea. I want to create a software (desktop or web application) that have some bellow features:

1. At beginning, I will add some forum (that I want to post topic to there) to software (to make it easier, at first the kind of forum is just vbulletin maybe)
2. Posting topic to forum automatically (Type topic content and select forum to post)
3. Manage all topic in all forum that we have post before.
4. Posting reply to each reply.

I think this software is very useful for those who want to post and manage a lot of topic in a lot of forum.
Do you think any soft like this one that was created already?
How can I get start with this? At now, can I use C#, ASP.NET to implement this idea?

Comment: Defending on person using it to do what. I want to use this soft to manage my company marketing topics. It will help us to save a lot of time to access to each forum.

Comment: For this,First thing, the forum must provide API to access and post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

Comment: Hi, what do you mean?:( I don't need a open source forum. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You basically described forum software. This is open source and gives you the code.